# Loading Images from Firebase Storage in Recycler Shows Images changing

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am loading my images from fire base storage using a recyclerview however as i load lets say image A an scroll to where that image view is recycled and will be used to show image B, i can still see image A briefly before it changes to image B,

Is there a way to avoid this ?

> Here is the code for my adapter

```
public class ComicRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComicRecyclerAdapter.ComicHolder> {


public ComicRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Comic> comicsInSection) {
    this.mComicsInSection = comicsInSection;
}

@Override
public ComicHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Bind the Comic object to the ComicHolder
    View comicView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_comic, parent, false);

    return new ComicRecyclerAdapter.ComicHolder(comicView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ComicHolder holder, int position) {
    Comic currentComic = mComicsInSection.get(position);

    storageRef.child(currentComic.getTitle() + "/"
            + currentComic.getCoverImage()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            //Load image using Picasso
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(uri)
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.coverImage, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //image loaded stop loading icon
                            holder.loadingComic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != mComicsInSection ? mComicsInSection.size() : 0);
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<Comic> comicsToAdd) {
    mComicsInSection.addAll(comicsToAdd);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    mComicsInSection.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ComicHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //Find all views needed
    @BindView(R.id.comic_cover_image)
    ImageView coverImage;
    @BindView(R.id.loading_comic)
    ProgressBar loadingComic;

    public ComicHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Reshaud, why you are putting this image url downloading code in recycler view ?

Comment: Hi @RishabhSaxena i put it there mainly to have it displayed in the recycler view since my class only stores the last part of the image name "imageA.jpg" is there a better way i should be doing this ?

Comment: I would suggest you to get list of image URLs first and then go to the adapter and simply use Picasso for loading it. Right Now what happening that when recycler view scrolls then it may be possible that you will get 3rd position URL first rather than 1st position which may lead you to unexpected result.

Comment: Hi @RishabhSaxena will try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Hi @RishabhSaxena that worked perfectly thanks !!

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170111/discussion-between-rishabh-saxena-and-reshaud-ally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to get list of image URLs first and then go to the adapter and simply use Picasso for loading it. right now what is happening that when recycler view scrolls then it may be possible that you will get 3rd position URL first rather than 1st position which may lead you to unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **[Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**, you can create **[GlideModule](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/storage/readme/)** class and use **[Firebase Ui Storage](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/storage/readme/)** dependency. Thanks to Firebase Ui Storage library, you don't have to use *[getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#public-taskuri-getdownloadurl)* method that is too slow with big data and when you use in adapter class' onBindViewHolder method, all images reload/shuffle again and again.

Add these dependencies in your application gradle:

```
// Find the latest Glide releases
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.x'
// If you're using Kotlin (and therefore, kapt), use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.x'
```

Create a new class for GlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Use Firebase image reference link directly in your adapter class:

```
  // top level variable
     FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BuildingAdapter.BuildingViewHolder holder,
                                     int position) {
 // create imagePath for Glide library. ImagePath = server url + image name
     StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(FIREBASE_STORAGE_MAIN_LINK + "/"+ data.get(position).getImageName());
    
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(storageRef)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_not_found)
                            .fitCenter())
                    .into(holder.im);
    }
```